# Which material was used for the 6502/6510/8500 MOSFETs?

Tags: commodore-64, 6502

I know that in the 80s, there was a shift from aluminum gate material to polycrystalline silicon. I wonder because the 6502 was released in 1975 and there were a lot of different implementations and versions of it in the 80s.
Did ICs use aluminum gate material anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [visual6502.org's page of die images](http://visual6502.org/images/6502/index.html), the chip was produced with "polysilicon" which is [apparently an alternative name for polycrystalline silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycrystalline_silicon).